# Facebook "like" button in PHP Nuke

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

It's not possible to use any of the "facebook like button" codes in my PHP Nuke website. It's not compatible there. The code just disappears. How can I get a "like-button" in my articles on my website created with PHP Nuke?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on how to modify the meta data in the head section of your pages

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/3590

Here's a good article on how to insert javascript into your page

http://phpnuke.org/modules.php?name=PHP-Nuke_HOWTO&page=javascript-in-php-nuke-modules.html

Here's a good article on how to insert HTML into your page

http://phpnuke.org/modules.php?name=PHP-Nuke_HOWTO&page=example-creation-html-template.html

Happy coding!